# Adding two different sized images Or Padding white pixels to make it to bigger size in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I have an image of size 1000x300, I want to make the image to the size of 4992x6400 . 
Basically **I don't want to Resize the image**

So there are two different ways, I thought we can do.

1. We can create the white image of the desired size which is  4992x6400  and add the white pixel image with the smaller image

```
import cv2
WhiteBackground = np.full(img.shape, 255, dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.imwrite(r"white.png",WhiteBackground)
readWhiteImage=cv2.imread(r"white.png")
readSmallImage=cv2.imread(r"small.png")
```

After this above code, I was struck how to add two different sized images 
I tried using `cv2.add` and `numpy.add` as images are of a different size and also used the `cv2.addWeighted` in none of it was successful.

I understood cv2.add and numpy.add will not work as images are of different size, but no idea about `cv2.addWeighted` as that also gave an error because of different size

2. Padding with White pixels at keeping the small images at the left top corner and padding white pixels towards left and bottom of it .. I didn't get any idea how to achieve this ...

Please help over this .
**Input Image**
[image: Input_Small image]

**Explected Output**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two possible ways to do that in Python/OpenCV. You can use cv2.copyMakeBorder() or you can use Numpy slicing to copy the input into the top left corner of a white background image. Here is the latter.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('numbers.png')
ht, wd, cc= img.shape

# create new image of desired size and color (white) for padding
ww = 4992 
hh = 6400
color = (255,255,255)
result = np.full((hh,ww,cc), color, dtype=np.uint8)

# set offsets for top left corner
xx = 0
yy = 0

# copy img image into center of result image
result[yy:yy+ht, xx:xx+wd] = img

# view result
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save result
cv2.imwrite("numbers_inserted.jpg", result)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It worked for same , when I am trying other image ,  i am getting below error     ```result[yy:yy+ht, xx:xx+wd] = img
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4812,6201,3) into shape (4812,4992,3)``` what might be the reason

Comment: Sorry, can you post your full script and the input image. It looks like you are trying to insert a larger image into a smaller one.

Comment: Yeah same thought I got while debugging .. I will try ! And keep you posted .. Thanks again